# Making a function which passes its arguments as :keys to another function

Tags: function, clojure, hashmap

I have a function which takes the following form

```
(defn foo [& {:keys [x y z]}]
  ...)
```

And I want to create a function which takes only the keys y and z, but always gives x the same value. I could write it like this

```
(defn bar [& {:keys [y z]}]
  (foo :x "blah" :y y :z z))
```

My only issue is that I have to repeat the {:keys ...} bit again, and the actual function foo has many more keys, which might change in the future. Is there some way I can make bar accept any key-value pairs, and just pass them all to foo, while making sure that x stays the same?

Comment: Do you need your function to be variadic? Or you just want to pass a map?

Comment: It needs to be variadic, I don't want to pass a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works and overrides any `:x` value passed to `bar`:

```
(defn foo [& {:keys [ x y ]}]
   [x y])

(defn bar [ & args ]
   (apply foo (concat args [:x "blah"])))
```

Comment: It would be a problem if args of bar already contain :x value.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking for. Thanks :)

Comment: @mobyte It's actually better if it just throws an error when :x is given to bar, because bar should only ever need one :x value.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the ampersand (&) you are declaring a variadic function.
You probably don't need your function to be variadic. 
You can simply do this:

```
(defn foo [{:keys [x y z]}]
  [x y z])

(defn bar [{:keys [y z] :as args}]  
  (foo (assoc args :x "blah")))
```

And you will call `bar` with a map like this: `(bar {:y 20 :z 10})`. If you really need `bar` to be a variadic function, you can just do this (`foo` is the same from above):

```
(defn bar [& {:keys [y z] :as args}]
   (foo (assoc args :x "blah"))
```

And you will continue to call `bar` like that: `(bar :y 10 :z 20)`. You can also make `foo` variadic but you will have to recreate arguments list yourself with something like `(flatten (map list (keys args) (vals args))))`.

Comment: No I definitely need it to be variadic. The actual foo function is just putting the values into a record, and some of those values might be `nil` when the function is run.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn bar [& {:keys [y z] :as args}]
  (apply foo (apply concat (assoc args :x "blah"))))
```